# Strange function behaviour c++, not returning same answer

Tags: c++, function, reference, dereference

I'm creating a queue class in c++ and am having trouble getting the front function to work. It is supposed to print the value of the first node in the queue. My queue.cpp class is here

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

queue::queue()
{
   front_p = NULL;
   back_p = NULL;
   current_size = 0;
}

void queue::enqueue(int item)
{
    node newnode = node(item, NULL);
   if (front_p == NULL) //queue is empty
    {
       front_p = &newnode;
       back_p = &newnode;
    }
   else 
   {
       back_p->next = &newnode;
       back_p = &newnode;
   }
   current_size ++;
}

int queue::dequeue()
{
   //if there is only one node
    if (front_p == back_p)
    {
        front_p = NULL;
        back_p = NULL;
    }
    //if there are two or more
    else
        front_p = front_p->next;
    current_size --;
}

int queue::front()
{
    if (front_p != NULL)
        return (*front_p).data;
}

bool queue::empty()
{
    if (front_p == NULL && back_p == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int queue::size()
{
    return current_size;
}
```

My header file (queue.h) is here

```
class queue
{
  public:
    queue(); // constructor - constructs a new empty queue.
    void enqueue( int item ); // enqueues item.
    int dequeue();  // dequeues the front item.
    int front();   // returns the front item without dequeuing it.
    bool empty();  // true iff the queue contains no items.
    int size();  // the current number of items in the queue.
    int remove(int item); // removes all occurrances of item 
      // from the queue, returning the number removed.

  private:
    class node  // node type for the linked list 
    {
       public:
           node(int new_data, node * next_node ){
              data = new_data ;
              next = next_node ;
           }
           int data ;
           node * next ;
    };

    node* front_p ;
    node* back_p ;
    int current_size ; // current number of elements in the queue.
};
```

test program (tester.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    queue q1;
    q1.enqueue(5);
    cout << "front: " << q1.front() << endl;
    cout << "front: " << q1.front() << endl;
    cout << "front: " << q1.front() << endl;
    q1.enqueue(10);
    cout << "front: " << q1.front() << endl;
    cout << "front: " << q1.front() << endl;
    cout << "size: " << q1.size() << endl;
}
```

makefile

```
all: tester

tester: queue.o tester.o
    g++ tester.o queue.o -o tester

tester.o: tester.cpp
    g++ -c tester.cpp

queue.o: queue.cpp queue.h
    g++ -c queue.cpp

clean:
    rm -f tester *.o
```

When I run my test program I get this:

```
front: 5
front: 6299744
front: 6299744
front: 10
front: 6299744
size: 2
```

As you can see, after the first enqueue, front returns what it is supposed to, the value of the front of the queue. But after that it returns some strange number and I have no idea where it comes from! Then when I enqueue again, it prints fine again. Only after calling front twice does it start printing messed up values. Can anyone help me understand whats going on?

Comment: You may want to check all your functions and those not using return may need a little help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program runs into undefined behavior because you have pointers to memory you don't own:

```
void queue::enqueue(int item)
{
   node newnode = node(item, NULL);
   if (front_p == NULL) //queue is empty
    {
       front_p = &newnode;
       back_p = &newnode;
    }
   else 
   {
       back_p->next = &newnode;
       back_p = &newnode;
   }
   current_size ++;
}
```

At the end of the function, `newnode` is destroyed, but `front_p` and `back_p` are still pointing to that memory location. Either allocate dynamically:

```
node* newnode = new node(item, NULL);
```

or use `std::shared_ptr<node>`.

Comment: It won't compile if I try to do this, it says I can't convert queue::node to queue::node*

Comment: `node* newnode = new node(item, NULL);`. See the asterisk? You can't write a queue class unless you have a good understanding of pointers and dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Dan In addition to what is said in the answer, `queue::front()` isn't implemented correctly. There is no specification of what to return when `front_o` is null.

Comment: you may also notice that the dequeue is incomplete.. I was just working on this part for now. Holy moly this was bugging me and my friend for a while. I'm new to c++, so thanks for bearing with! Thank you~ Luchian!